# pass matrix by reference and scan values

Tags: c, matrix, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to scan values into a matrix that is passed by reference to a function and that's not compiled.
What's wrong?
I think the problem is in line of `scanf` but I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** initMatrix(int lines, int columns) {
    int i;
    int** matrix;
    matrix = (int**) calloc(lines, sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (int*) calloc(columns, sizeof(int));
    }
    return matrix;
}

void fillMatrixValues(int*** matrixA, int lines, int columns) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            scanf("%d", matrixA[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void printMatrix(int** matrix, int lines, int columns) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main() {
    int** matrixA;
    int lines = 2, columns = 2;
    matrixA = initMatrix(lines, columns);
    fillMatrixValues(&matrixA, lines, columns);
    printMatrix(matrixA, lines, columns);
}
```

Comment: At least one problem is here `void fillMatrixValues(int ***matrixA, int lines, int columns)`. The matrixA should be `int **` not `int ***`.

Comment: Generally check the return value of scanf to protect against misunderstandings. In a debug experiment print everything immediatly after you scanfed it. There are many possible mistakes to make with scanf. In short, get your scanf tested and running before attempting to do anything with its result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void main` -> undefined behaviour

Use

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
```

You should check return value of `scanf`

```
if (scanf("%d", matrixA[i][j]) != 1)
{
    // failed
}
```

Next problem

```
void fillMatrixValues(int ***matrixA, int lines, int columns)
fillMatrixValues(&matrixA, lines, columns)
```

to

```
void fillMatrixValues(int **matrixA, int lines, int columns)
fillMatrixValues(matrixA, lines, columns)
```